# MySQL: Using MAX in a window function not returning highest values

Tags: mysql, function, window, max

I am seeking to find the highest grade scores for each student_id.
The grade scores are kept in this table:

Enrollments table:

| student_id | course_id | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 95 |
| 2 | 3 | 95 |
| 1 | 1 | 90 |
| 1 | 2 | 99 |
| 3 | 1 | 80 |
| 3 | 2 | 75 |
| 3 | 3 | 82 |

The correct result should be:

| student_id | course_id | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 99 |
| 2 | 2 | 95 |
| 3 | 3 | 82 |

Here is the query I am trying:

```
SELECT student_id, course_id, grade
 FROM Enrollments
 GROUP BY student_id
 HAVING grade = (SELECT MAX(grade) OVER(PARTITION BY student_id))
 ORDER BY student_id ASC
```

However with this query, the results I'm getting are:

| student_id | course_id | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 90 |
| 2 | 2 | 95 |
| 3 | 3 | 80 |

i.e. student 1's grade is 90, when it should be 99, and student 2's grade is 80, when it should be 82.

It seems like the issue is this query is only selecting the max grade from the first course_id in the table, but I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row_number, for your desired result

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`student_id` int, `course_id` int, `grade` int)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`student_id`, `course_id`, `grade`)
> VALUES
>     (2, 2, 95),
>     (2, 3, 95),
>     (1, 1, 90),
>     (1, 2, 99),
>     (3, 1, 80),
>     (3, 2, 75),
>     (3, 3, 82)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `student_id`, `course_id`, `grade`
> FROM (SELECT `student_id`, `course_id`, `grade`
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `student_id` ORDER BY `grade` DESC) rn
> FROM Table1) t1
> WHERE rn= 1
> ```
>
> ```
> student_id | course_id | grade
> ---------: | --------: | ----:
>          1 |         2 |    99
>          2 |         2 |    95
>          3 |         3 |    82
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc4bcceb84a64898a002efbdb130cb97)*

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you happen to have any insight on why the window function wasn't working in the way I tried (with MAX())? I'm trying to figure out what I'm misunderstanding about the logic. Thanks!

Comment: aa window function like in my example, works row for row, that iswhy you have a CTE or a outer SELECT with them . You problem ist that your query doesn't wirk in th dbfiddle, and a further thuing is that you have to keep in mind a result set are **unordered** that is why you need constructions like the other answer or like in my case i give an order with the row_number

Answer (score 2):

Please try this query.

```
SELECT e.student_id, e.course_id, e.grade
FROM Enrollments e INNER JOIN 
(SELECT student_id as student_id, MAX(grade) as grade FROM Enrollments GROUP BY student_id) sbq 
ON e.student_id = sbq.student_id
WHERE e.grade = sbq.grade;
```

Comment: Just curious - Why WHERE instead of AND

Comment: @Strawberry Usually it is recommended to use only Unique key column in Join condition, and others in WHERE. Here student_id is not unique, but is identity column whereas grade is a fact. Although In this particular it would have worked fine with AND also.

Comment: Nope, that ain't the rule.